# Will distilled water dissolve aluminum

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have an aluminum drinking-water container. If I fill with distilled water will the aluminum eventually be attacked by the water?

Comment: No, unless you destroy the oxide layer.

Comment: Don't repost bad questions https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94045/aluminum-in-contact-with-distilled-water

Comment: Sure aluminum can be attacked by water.  Happens all the time when it rains on aluminum siding, as we can plainly see.  Why do people outside of deserts buy that stuff?  Uh ... not so, as you might have guessed.

Comment: In a clean controlled environment Al is resistant ,but in the real world of CO2, traces of salts , etc, it will pit. Al foil wrap put over food will often corrode through overnight, if not protected by oil and grease from the food.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your aluminum drinking-water container has a thin coating of aluminum oxide which is unreactive to water, whether or not it is distilled.